# apache rewrite to lighttpd rewrite

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I use this rule in our Apache webserver:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-*\.jpg$                                                                                                                                                                
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                                                                                                      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                                                                                                      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?req=$1 [QSA]
```

Can you help me, how can I migrate this to 1.4.20 lighttpd+[url_rewrite-ifnotfile](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository/revisions/2647)?

I found similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613979/apache-rewrite-rule-to-lighttpd) and [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite), but I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

As per my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613979/apache-rewrite-rule-to-lighttpd)  please use the following: (i've amended the  rewrite to fit your request):

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^(.*)$" => "/index.php?req=$1"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the apache setup, your best option in this case would be to upgrade to 1.4.24+ otherwise these rewrite rules will start to get complex as you will need to direct to every file that exists. Something like this for example:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/index.php$" => "/index.php",
    "^/page1.php$" => "/page1.php",
    "^/page2.php$" => "/page2.php",
    .
    .
    .
    "^/pageN.php$" => "/page.php",
    .
    .
    .
    "^/uploads/uploadedfile.pdf$" => "/uploads/uploadedfile.pdf",
    .
    .
    .
    "(.*)" => "/index.php?req=$1"
)
```

If your application doesn't have many files the user needs to access directly you could solve this problem as above. However once you start dealing with uploaded content or anything dynamic you will run into problems.

Personally i've always avoided such problems in the past by adding any content i don't want lighty to rewrite into a sub directory then you can use a wildcard (this may or may not work in your case) like so :

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/content/(.*)$" => "/content/$1",
    "(.*)" => "/index.php?req=$1"
)
```

If neither of the above is any use, You could use a php script to serve all your dynamic content, but this comes with its own set of problems and inflexibility. For example:

```
<?php

    $fullPath = '/path/to/files/' . $_GET['filename'];

    if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

        // Parse Info / Get Extension 
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

        // Determine Content Type 
        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
            case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
            case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
            case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
            case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
            case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
            case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
            case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
            default: $ctype="application/force-download";
        }

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-Type: $ctype");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);

    } else
        exit('File Not Found');
?>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, it does not work, but I can use in my 1.4.20 version this url.rewrite-if-not-file setting (rewrite patch from 1.4.24+). do you have any idea, what's the good config by this setting? I can't replace this lighttpd.